Tween/teen fantasy book with twins, one of which swaps appearance with a girl
I read a book a long time ago and only remember some odd plot points, maybe someone can identify it? I remember that the twin boy main characters were supposed to be one person, but got split or something in the womb and were identical twins. At some point, one of the twins swaps colors (skin, hair, eyes) with the main female character to hide his identity or something? At the end of the book, one of the twins sacrifices himself and gets trapped inside a door to seal it (I think). Does anyone recognize this book? It’s nothing published after 2018, I read this a while ago. I read it on kindle, so I don’t know what the cover looks like.
